# Is there a closed-form lower bound for monic polynomials of even degree?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, polynomials, upper-lower-bounds

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$,
$$f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots + a_1x+a_0$$

where $n$ is even and $a_i\in \mathbb{R}$. It is then not difficult to show that $f$ is bounded below. This leads to the question:

1. Does there exist a closed-form (**not necessarily optimal**) lower bound for such a polynomial in terms of its coefficients $a_i$?
2. Can this closed-form be expressed as a (multi-variate) polynomial in the coefficients $a_i$?

I imagine that the answer to both is yes, but I have no idea how to prove this. I thought a bit about three cases below.

---

- $n=2$

For monic quadratics, a sufficient lower bound is $a_0 - \frac{a_1^2}{4}$. This satisfies (1), (2) and it is also optimal.

- $n=4$

In this case, we could differentiate to find the stationary points of $f$, and write the minimum of $f$ evaluated at these points in a closed-form (using the absolute value function). This satisfies (1) and is again optimal, but does not satisfy (2).

- $n \ge 6$

No immediate solutions, since polynomials of degree $\ge5$ have no closed-form solutions.

Suppose that $\{r_0,...r_k\}$ is the zero set of $f$, in ascending order. Then $f$ attains its minimum in $[r_0,r_k]$. (If the zero set is empty, then $0$ is a lower bound.) Thus, it may be possible to simplify this problem by using bounds on the locations of the roots of polynomials, if any are known.

Comment: I suggest mimicking the standard proof that such a polynomial has a global minimum. First find $M$ such that $f(x)>0$ for $|x|>M$; then find a lower bound for $f(x)$ on the interval $[-M,M]$. Both of these steps can be done explicitly in terms of the coefficients.

Comment: @GregMartin Hmm, the proof I would use to show that $f$ has a global minimum is entirely non-constructive. I'll try to make it constructive, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I’m not mistaken, let $S=1+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{|a_i|}$. Then $-S^n$ should be such a lower bound.

Indeed, if $|x| \geq S$, then $f(x) \geq S^n-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{S^{i}|a_{i}|}\geq S^n-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{|a_i|S^{n-1}} \geq S^{n-1} \geq 0$.

But if $|x| \leq S$, then $f(x) \geq -\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{|a_i|S^i} \geq -S^{n-1}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{|a_i|} \geq -S^n$.

Comment: Nice, thanks! I guess you got this by looking at Lagrange's bound? You could further make this bound polynomial by replacing $S$ with $(n+1) + \Sigma a_i^2$. Also, I appreciate that I asked for a not necessarily optimal bound, but I feel like this bound could nevertheless be tightened easily, even with the same reasoning. For instance, in the very last step, don't you actually get $S^{n-1}-S^n$ as the lower bound, which is better?

Comment: You’re correct, I went for the simplest possible bound. I agree that I can get $S^{n-1}-S^n$ as the lowest bound without any more work. I don’t understand what you call polynomial, though. What is the fundamental difference between $\left((n+1)+\sum_i{a_i^2}\right)^n$ and my $S^n$?

Comment: $-S^n$ will have absolute value signs when expanded, whereas $-((n+1)+\Sigma a_i^2)^n$ is a polynomial only in $\{a_i\}$, which was the (somewhat arbitrary) second part of my question.

Comment: Ah, I understand. This can also be slightly improved, to $1+n/4+\sum_i{a_i^2}$, or $1+n/2+\frac{1}{2}\sum_i{a_i^2}$, since there are $n$ coefficients and $|x| \leq x^2+1/4$.